# VSIX install failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vsix

I downloaded extension in visual studio 2019  but while installing error occurred.

[image: image of error]

install log is this:

```
  4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - -------------------------------------------
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - 16.9.2017
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - -------------------------------------------
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - Command line parameters:
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\Usman\Downloads\ProductivityPowerPack2017.vsix
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - -------------------------------------------
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
     4/25/2021 8:41:33 PM - -------------------------------------------
     4/25/2021 8:41:34 PM - System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
 dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
 match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
     File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Validation, Version=15.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
        at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.AddInstalledIsolatedShells(Version
 vsVersion, IntPtr userToken)
        at VSIXInstaller.SupportedSKUs.InitializeSupportedSKUs(IntPtr userToken)
        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.InitializeSupportedSKUs(ICommandLineData
 cmdLineData, IntPtr duplicatedUserToken)
        at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
        at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
 exceptionObject)
     
     WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
     To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
     Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
     To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: Is the name of the extension secrete?

Comment: @S.M. no its not

Comment: Repair your VS install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run a repair of your Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

If repair doesn't work, you might've moved your VS install and now it won't install anything.

This is because it "might" be finding the VS Installer in a directory OTHER than the standard one. Reinstall the installer itself, then try to install the extension or whatevs

Answer (score 0):

Check if this path exists on your C drive. The "Packages" folder is used to save VS extensions which VS needs. I'd moved mine to F drive to save space. The error message didn't help me much.

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages